# Im using a vector and file reader,the goal is that it should print info from text file like name and lastname

Tags: c++

I'm using a `vector` and file reader, the goal is to print info from a text file like name and last name using a search algorithm, like a phone book.

I have tried using find, and it works, because it finds specific input of what I write. But I want it to work like a phone book. If I searched a name, it should print out the last name and phone number.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main()
{

    vector<string> person;
    string word;

    ifstream out;
    out.open("a.txt");

    while (!out.eof()) {
        getline(out, word);
        person.push_back(word);
    }

    string item;
    std::cout << "Write the name you want to search" << item << "\n";
    cin >> item;

    if (find(person.begin(), person.end(), item) != person.end()) {
        std::cout << "Namn::" << item << "\n";
    }
    else {
        std::cout << "not found" << "\n";
    }

// John from text file a.txt, but if possible it should print out his last name and
// mobile 
// like this.
// John
// Stock
// 0700044

    system("pause");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Define a data structure that represents a person, and use those instead of plain strings.

Comment: Instead of vector u can use map as data structrue. u can store name as key and class object as second parameter. So u can print the class members when needed

Comment: You should fix your title to be more concise. You need more details on the problem. What's the file format? What output are you getting? What do you want it to look like? You're searching by first names? So does that mean there could be multiple outputs 'cause lots of people have same first names? etc